# Parse-server Cloud Code Function was not called

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform

I am receiving the error [Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0) while calling this Cloud Code function in parse.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("AddFriendRequest", function (request, response) {

var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendsIncoming");

var FRequest = new FriendRequest();

var user = request.user;

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
query.find({
    success: function (people) {
        if(people.length == 0)
        {
            response.success(-5);
            return;
        }

        var person = people[0];
        FRequest.set("OwnerID", user.id);
        FRequest.set("TargetFriend", person.id);
        FRequest.set("Status", 0);

        var query = new Parse.Query("FriendsIncoming");
        query.equalTo("OwnerID", user.id);
        query.equalTo("TargetFriendID", person.id);
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {

                if (results.length > 0) {
                    response.success(1);
                    return;
                }
                FRequest.save(null, {
                    success: function (Friend) {
                        response.success(2);
                    },
                    error: function (Friend, error) {
                        response.error(3);
                    }
                });
                response.error(-2);

            },
            error: function () {
                response.error(-1);
            }
        });
    }
    ,
    error: function (Friend, error) {
        response.error(-4);
    }

});


});
```

I am calling it using the below code in swift:  I did not write the Javascript myself so there may be an obvious issue but there is nothing I can tell from glancing at it with no prior knowledge to JS.

```
    var name : NSString
    name = "kooshesh"
    //let parameters : [NSObject : AnyObject]
    let parameters = ["TargetFriendID" : name]

    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("AddFriendRequest", withParameters: parameters) { results, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Your error handling here
        } else {
            print(results)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invalid function seems due to function not found. Make sure there any typo, or AddFriendRequest in main.js or be required in main.js. Or the cloud code path you specify.

Comment: BTW in your code, response(2) and response(3) seems not be possible to response to client, due to response(-2) will be called before  FRequest.save's callback been called